# How to resize two divs on the click of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two divs that are each 15% height position one on top the other on the bottom so as to leave a space 70% height in the middle. On click of a link, I want the height of each div to grow to 50% and then shrink back to 15% to create a blinking effect so content in the middle area can change out of view.

Does anyone have an idea of what jquery or css I can use to accomplish this?

I tried this:

```
   $( ".mnav li" ).click(function() {
  $( ".header" ).animate({
    height: 50%
  }, 5000,});
```

with the intent of making the div 50% on click

Update:: How can I edit this code below so that it removes the class right after the animation with blink is complete so that If I click on another link it will run again?

```
$( '.mnav a' ).click(function() {
  $( '.border' ).addClass('blink');
});
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: 50% would need to be a string. Also, you have an extra comma after 5000. I assume you have errors in your console...

Comment: yeah, so far this isnt working...

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of what you've done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <title>Temp</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#div2').hide('slow');
        $('#div1').animate({height:'50%'})
        $('#div3').animate({height:'50%'})

        $('#div2').show('slow');
        $('#div1').animate({height:'15%'})
        $('#div3').animate({height:'15%'})
      });


    })
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

     <div id="div1" style="background-color:red;width:100%;height:15%;">
     </div>
     <div id="div2" style="background-color:blue;width:100%;height:70%;">
     </div>
     <div id="div3" style="background-color:black;width:100%;height:15%;">
     </div>
     <button id="btn">Click</button>


    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body,
#wrapper,
#left,
#right {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; width: 960px; // width optional 
}
#left {
    background: yellow; float: left; width: 360px; // width optional but recommended 
}
#right {
    background: grey;
    margin-left: 360px;

}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lech/ay2snyc2/)

Comment: is there a way to do it so the show and hide action happens on one click?